# Helm: Passing array values through --set

Tags: kubernetes-helm

i have a cronjob helm chat, i can define many jobs in values.yaml and cronjob.yaml will provision my jobs. I have faced an issue when setting the image tag id in command line, following command throw no errors but it wont update jobs image tag to new one.

```
helm upgrade cronjobs cronjobs/ --wait --set job.myservice.image.tag=b70d744
```

cronjobs will run with old image tag how can i resolve this?

here is my cronjobs.yaml

```
{{- $chart_name := .Chart.Name }}
{{- $chart_version := .Chart.Version | replace "+" "_" }}
{{- $release_name := .Release.Name }}

{{- range $job := .Values.jobs }}
---
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  namespace: "{{ $job.namespace }}"
  name: "{{ $release_name }}-{{ $job.name }}"
  labels:
    chart: "{{ $chart_name }}-{{ $chart_version }}"
spec:
  concurrencyPolicy: {{ $job.concurrencyPolicy }}
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: {{ $job.failedJobsHistoryLimit }}
  suspend: {{ $job.suspend }}
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            app: {{ $release_name }}
            cron: {{ $job.name }}
        spec:
          containers:
          - image: "{{ $job.image.repository }}:{{ $job.image.tag }}"
            imagePullPolicy: {{ $job.image.imagePullPolicy }}
            ports:
              - name: http
                containerPort: 80
                protocol: TCP
            name: {{ $job.name }}
            args:
{{ toYaml $job.args | indent 12 }}
            env:
{{ toYaml $job.image.env | indent 12 }}
            volumeMounts:
            - name: nfs
              mountPath: "{{ $job.image.nfslogpath }}"
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
          imagePullSecrets:
            - name: {{ $job.image.secret }}
          volumes:
            - name: nfs
              nfs:
                server: "{{ $job.image.server }}"
                path: "{{ $job.image.nfspath }}"
                readOnly: false
  schedule: {{ $job.schedule | quote }}
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: {{ $job.successfulJobsHistoryLimit }}
  {{- end }}
```

here is my values.yaml

```
jobs:
  - name: myservice
    namespace: default
    image:
      repository: xxx.com/myservice
      tag: fe4544
      pullPolicy: Always
      secret: xxx
      nfslogpath: "/var/logs/"
      nfsserver: "xxx"
      nfspath: "/nfs/xxx/cronjobs/"
      nfsreadonly: false
      env:
    schedule: "*/5 * * * *"
    args:
    failedJobsHistoryLimit: 1
    successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 3
    concurrencyPolicy: Forbid
    suspend: false

  - name: myservice2
    namespace: default
    image:
      repository: xxxx/myservice2
      tag: 1dff39a
      pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
      secret: xxxx
      nfslogpath: "/var/logs/"
      nfsserver: "xxxx"
      nfspath: "/nfs/xxx/cronjobs/"
      nfsreadonly: false
      env:
    schedule: "*/30 * * * *"
    args:
    failedJobsHistoryLimit: 1
    successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 2
    concurrencyPolicy: Forbid
    suspend: false
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you are using array in your **values.yaml** file, please see [related issue](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/1987)

**Alternative solution**

- Your **values.yaml** is missing values for *args* and *env*. I've set them in my example, as well as changed indent to 14
- Your **cronjob.yaml** `server: "{{ $job.image.server }}"` value is null, and I've changed it to `.image.nfsserver`

Instead of using array, just separate your services like in example below:

**values.yaml**

```
jobs:
  myservice:
    namespace: default
    image:
      repository: xxx.com/myservice
      tag: fe4544
      pullPolicy: Always
      secret: xxx
      nfslogpath: "/var/logs/"
      nfsserver: "xxx"
      nfspath: "/nfs/xxx/cronjobs/"
      nfsreadonly: false
      env:
        key: val
    schedule: "*/5 * * * *"
    args:
      key: val
    failedJobsHistoryLimit: 1
    successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 3
    concurrencyPolicy: Forbid
    suspend: false

  myservice2:
    namespace: default
    image:
      repository: xxxx/myservice2
      tag: 1dff39a
      pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
      secret: xxxx
      nfslogpath: "/var/logs/"
      nfsserver: "xxxx"
      nfspath: "/nfs/xxx/cronjobs/"
      nfsreadonly: false
      env:
        key: val
    schedule: "*/30 * * * *"
    args:
      key: val
    failedJobsHistoryLimit: 1
    successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 2
    concurrencyPolicy: Forbid
    suspend: false
```

In your **cronjob.yaml** use `{{- range $job, $val := .Values.jobs }}` to iterate over values.

Use *$job* where you used *{{ $job.name }}*.

Access values like *suspend* with *{{ .suspend }}* instead of *{{ $job.suspend }}*

**cronjob.yaml**

```
{{- $chart_name := .Chart.Name }}
{{- $chart_version := .Chart.Version | replace "+" "_" }}
{{- $release_name := .Release.Name }}

{{- range $job, $val := .Values.jobs }}
---
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  namespace: {{ .namespace }} 
  name: "{{ $release_name }}-{{ $job }}"
  labels:
    chart: "{{ $chart_name }}-{{ $chart_version }}"
spec:
  concurrencyPolicy: {{ .concurrencyPolicy }}
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: {{ .failedJobsHistoryLimit }}
  suspend: {{ .suspend }}
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            app: {{ $release_name }}
            cron: {{ $job }}
        spec:
          containers:
          - image: "{{ .image.repository }}:{{ .image.tag }}"
            imagePullPolicy: {{ .image.imagePullPolicy }}
            ports:
              - name: http
                containerPort: 80
                protocol: TCP
            name: {{ $job }}
            args:
{{ toYaml .args | indent 14 }}
            env:
{{ toYaml .image.env | indent 14 }}
            volumeMounts:
            - name: nfs
              mountPath: "{{ .image.nfslogpath }}"
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
          imagePullSecrets:
            - name: {{ .image.secret }}
          volumes:
            - name: nfs
              nfs:
                server: "{{ .image.nfsserver }}"
                path: "{{ .image.nfspath }}"
                readOnly: false
  schedule: {{ .schedule | quote }}
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: {{ .successfulJobsHistoryLimit }}
{{- end }}
```

Passing values using *--set* :

`helm upgrade cronjobs cronjobs/ --wait --set jobs.myservice.image.tag=b70d744`

**Example:**

`helm install --debug --dry-run --set jobs.myservice.image.tag=my123tag .`

```
...
HOOKS:
MANIFEST:

---
# Source: foo/templates/cronjob.yaml
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: "illmannered-iguana-myservice"
  labels:
    chart: "foo-0.1.0"
spec:
  concurrencyPolicy: Forbid
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: 1
  suspend: false
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            app: illmannered-iguana
            cron: myservice
        spec:
          containers:
          - image: "xxx.com/myservice:my123tag"
            imagePullPolicy:
            ports:
              - name: http
                containerPort: 80
                protocol: TCP
            name: myservice
            args:
              key: val

            env:
              key: val

            volumeMounts:
            - name: nfs
              mountPath: "/var/logs/"
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
          imagePullSecrets:
            - name: xxx
          volumes:
            - name: nfs
              nfs:
                server: "xxx"
                path: "/nfs/xxx/cronjobs/"
                readOnly: false
  schedule: "*/5 * * * *"
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 3
---
# Source: foo/templates/cronjob.yaml
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: "illmannered-iguana-myservice2"
  labels:
    chart: "foo-0.1.0"
spec:
  concurrencyPolicy: Forbid
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: 1
  suspend: false
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            app: illmannered-iguana
            cron: myservice2
        spec:
          containers:
          - image: "xxxx/myservice2:1dff39a"
            imagePullPolicy:
            ports:
              - name: http
                containerPort: 80
                protocol: TCP
            name: myservice2
            args:
              key: val

            env:
              key: val

            volumeMounts:
            - name: nfs
              mountPath: "/var/logs/"
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
          imagePullSecrets:
            - name: xxxx
          volumes:
            - name: nfs
              nfs:
                server: "xxxx"
                path: "/nfs/xxx/cronjobs/"
                readOnly: false
  schedule: "*/30 * * * *"
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 2
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Passing array is now supported using `--set "test={x,y,z}"` and `--set servers[0].port=80`  as explained in other answsers.

Comment: i your cronjob.yaml you define $val but never used it, inside the range loop if I try to access .env it returns an error, nill pointer evaluating interface, are you sure this is the right way to access variables inside the loop ?

Comment: @edbighead Can you please answer my question here --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69173783/setting-up-multiple-cronjob-using-helm My question is relatively easy.

Answer (score 112):

If you need to pass array values you can use curly braces (unix shell require quotes):

```
--set test={x,y,z}
--set "test={x,y,z}"
```

Result YAML:

```
test:
  - x
  - y
  - z
```

Source: https://helm.sh/docs/intro/using_helm/#the-format-and-limitations-of---set

EDITED : added double-quotes for unix shell like bash

Comment: This does not seem to work, at least as of `2.16` version of helm. It gives `Error: This command needs 2 arguments: release name, chart path` when running something like `helm upgrade opining-frog deploy/traefik/chart --set externalIps={a,b,c} --debug`. Which version of helm are you using?

Comment: Have you test with --set first?

Example: helm upgrade --set pwd=3jk$o2,z=f\30.e redis ./redis

Source: https://v2.helm.sh/docs/helm/#helm-upgrade

Comment: Thanks a lot, that did not work, but I got it to work by scaping the commas (in case someone else faces same issue): `helm upgrade opining-frog deploy/traefik/chart --set externalIps={a\,b\,c}`. Few hours battling with this.

Comment: Thanks David! Seems the following will resolve the stated error as well: `--set "service.ListValue={a,b,c}"`

Answer (score 54):

[Update for Helm 2.5.0](https://helm.sh/docs/intro/using_helm/#the-format-and-limitations-of---set)

> As of Helm 2.5.0, it is possible to access list items using an array index syntax.

For example, `--set servers[0].port=80` becomes:

```
servers:
  - port: 80
```

Comment: @justin.m.chase - don't agree. This is setting an array item to a map. Whilst this is useful, it's not what the question asked.

Answer (score 9):

For the sake of completeness I'll post a more complex example with Helm 3.

Let's say that you have this in your `values.yaml` file:

```
extraEnvVars:
- name: CONFIG_BACKEND_URL
  value: "https://api.example.com"
- name: CONFIG_BACKEND_AUTH_USER
  value: "admin"
- name: CONFIG_BACKEND_AUTH_PWD
  value: "very-secret-password"
```

You can `--set` just the `value` for the `CONFIG_BACKEND_URL` this way:

```
helm install ... --set "extraEnvVars[0].value=http://172.23.0.1:36241"
```

The other two variables (i.e. `CONFIG_BACKEND_AUTH_USER` and `CONFIG_BACKEND_AUTH_PWD`) will be read from the `values.yaml` file since we're not overwriting them with a `--set`.
Same for `extraEnvVars[0].name` which will be `CONFIG_BACKEND_URL` as per `values.yaml`.

Source: https://helm.sh/docs/intro/using_helm/#the-format-and-limitations-of---set

Comment: I'm trying to use this example in my own code and the same --set instruction is deleting all other items from the array and only the items set by the --set operation are left. Any idea why?

Answer (score 8):

On helm 3. This works for me.
--set "servers[0].port=80" --set "servers[1].port=8080"

Comment: This also works for nested elements. 
An example :  
`"elements[0].arguments[0].value=firstValue"`
`"elements[0].arguments[1].value=secondValue"`